# Function calls between strtok?

Tags: c, strtok

So I'm using `strtok` to split an char array by `" "`. Then I place each word I split into a function that will determine a value for the word based on a list. However everything I place the function call in middle of the while loop to of splitting the `char` array it stops.

Do I have to split the array, store it in another array and then go through the second array?

```
    p = strtok(temp, " ");

    while (p != NULL) {
        value =  get_score(score, scoresize, p);
        points = points + value;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

So as long as `value = get_score(score, scoresize, p);` is there the `while` loops break after the first word.

Comment: What does you get_score() function look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtok()` uses a hidden state variable to keep track of the source string position. If you use `strtok` again, directly or indirectly in `get_score()`, this hidden state will be changed as to make the call `p = strtok(NULL, " ");` meaningless.

Do not use `strtok()` this way, either use the improved version `strtok_r` [standardized in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html), available on many systems. Or re-implement it with `strspn` and `strcspn`:

```
#include <string.h>
char *my_strtok_r(char *s, char *delim, char **context) {
    char *token = NULL;

    if (s == NULL)
        s = *context;

    /* skip initial delimiters */
    s += strspn(s, delim);
    if (*s != '\0') {
        /* we have a token */
        token = s;
        /* skip the token */
        s += strcspn(s, delim);
        if (*s != '\0') {
            /* cut the string to terminate the token */
            *s++ = '\0';
        }
    }
    *context = s;
    return token;
}

...

    char *state;
    p = my_strtok_r(temp, " ", &state);

    while (p != NULL) {
        value =  get_score(score, scoresize, p);
        points = points + value;
        p = my_strtok_r(NULL, " ", &state);
    }
```